# How can treat the connection name as parameter in ActiveWorkbook.Connections in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, vba

First of all , I am now working on a Excel Matrix extracting data by ODBC connection with multiple library.

I have already created the VBA script for dynamic SQL query by passing parameter from Excel Cells.

However, I am now getting stuck at the point by Dim the connection name in parameter in the VBA.

```
Dim sSQL As Variant
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim rDest As Range
Dim AWS As Worksheet
Dim Table1 As Variant
Dim Current As Variant
Dim Year As Range
Dim PD_Fm As Range
Dim PD_To As Range
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim Connection_Name As Variant



'--Defin Table"1-3" as cell
Set AWS = ActiveSheet
Table1 = Worksheets("CO CODE").Range("B22:E33")
Current = Worksheets("CO CODE").Range("G7:G18")
Connection_Name = Range("G22").ListObject.DisplayName
Set Year = Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(6, 3)
Set PD_Fm = Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(7, 3)
Set PD_To = Worksheets("MASTER").Cells(8, 3)

myArray = Worksheets("CO CODE").Range("B18:E29")

'--Define SINGLEQUOTE for SQL QUERY USE
Const SINGLEQUOTE = "'"


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 12

sSQL = Array( _
        "SELECT Sum(GLH.LHDRAM-GLH.LHCRAM)" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM " & Table1(i, 1) & ", " & Table1(i, 2) & ", " & Table1(i, 3) & ", " & Table1(i, 4) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE GHH.HHJNEN = GLH.LHJNEN AND GHH.HHYEAR = GLH.LHYEAR AND GHH.HHPERD = GLH.LHPERD AND GH" _
        , _
        "H.HHBOOK = GLH.LHBOOK AND GLH.LHIAN = GCR.CRIAN AND ((GLH.LHID='LH') AND (GLH.LHYEAR=" & Year & ") AND (GCR.CRSG02=GSV.SVSGVL And GCR.CRSG02=" & SINGLEQUOTE & "" & Current(i, 1) & "" & SINGLEQUOTE & ") AND (GSV.SVSGMN='ACCOUNT') AND (GLH.LHPERD>=" & PD_Fm & " And GLH." _
        , "LHPERD<=" & PD_To & "))")





With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Connection_Name).ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = sSQL

Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With



Next i
```

I am trying to get the connection name from Excel Cell and put the name back to the script
 `With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("""""PARAMTER"""").ODBCConnection`

I have try my best to search the relevant information from here and Google but still got no answer.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: What error are you getting and at what line?

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting and at what line?

Add the sheet you are getting the cell value from.

Change

```
Connection_Name = Range("G22").ListObject.DisplayName
```

to have the sheet object

```
Connection_Name = Worksheets("CO CODE").Range("G22").ListObject.DisplayName
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your reply

I got the error message
 'subscript out of range' 
at this script 
'With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Connection_Name).ODBCConnection'

Answer (score 0):

Just Googling around and found out that the there is no connection between the Excel VBA Listobject Name and Connection Name

therefore, can only build up a connection name table in another worksheet as work around.

May refer the details of the answer from the following link.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/modify-a-connection-string-in-a-odbc-connection/309c6c73-042a-43f7-926b-c3a5c29e4e8e